# Custom NSView for NSTableView not updating components

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I created a custom NSView for a NSTableView.

I am trying to fill the fields I created in it using the Interface Builder but I can't. I would say each component is properly linked and the code is OK.

This is the function

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    Account *account = (Account *)[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:row];

    AccountTableCellViewController *controller = [[AccountTableCellViewController alloc] init];
    controller.subtitleLabel.stringValue = account.name;
    [controller.titleLabel setStringValue:account.num];
    NSLog(@"%@", controller.titleLabel);
    return [controller view];
}
```

And here is the picture of the bindings:

[image]

The table shows all the rows correctly, but is not filling the NSTextFields as expected.

UPDATE:

This is how it looks like (not updating views):
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of how it's not filling the NSTextField's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels haven't been loaded from the nib yet. I'd just create an extra account instance variable in your view controller, assign it there, then load the information in `-(void)awakeFromNib`

Comment: The problem is that is not updating the textfields, not its position :)

Comment: Silly me, should've read the question properly :p  I've edited my answer to provide a few suggestions.

Comment: controller.titleLabel is null, apparently the controls have not been initialized. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: The labels haven't been loaded from the nib yet.  I'd probably just create an extra account instance variable in your view controller, assign it there, then load the information in `-(void)awakeFromNib`

Comment: Hi there! That was the solution. Can you put it in the answer so I can vote you?